# Is there a way to know if a user has logged in with an x509 certificate in Keycloak on the application level?

Tags: authentication, certificate, keycloak, x509, mtls

We need this information to provide restricted functionality. Would be great if this information could be included in the access token. We use Keycloak version 16.1.1.

We try to put client certificate in the token using script mapper, but the request header "ssl-client-cert" is empty:

```
nginx_cert_header = keycloakSession.getContext().getRequestHeaders().getHeaderString('ssl-client-cert');
token.getOtherClaims().put("client-cert", nginx_cert_header);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Certificate Bound Access Tokens**

Since version 4.0.0.Final keycloak supports [Certificate Bound Access Tokens](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-mtls-08#section-4.4).

At client configuration there are a panel named "Advanced Settings" with that option "OAuth 2.0 Mutual TLS Certificate Bound Access Tokens Enabled" described as "This enables support for OAuth 2.0 Mutual TLS Certificate Bound Access Tokens, which means that keycloak bind an access token and a refresh token with a X.509 certificate of a token requesting client exchanged in mutual TLS between keycloak's Token Endpoint and this client. These tokens can be treated as Holder-of-Key tokens instead of bearer tokens."

Enabling this will add a new claim to access token and refresh token. Your app could check that claim to verify if user has logged in using client certificate.

**Step-Up Authentication**

Another option, perhaps, is update your keycloak to version 18.0.0 and use [Step-Up Authentication](https://embesozzi.medium.com/keycloak-step-up-authentication-for-web-and-api-3ef4c9f25d42). That way you can require a higher level of authentication for operations where you need to "provide restricted functionality".

Comment: When I enable this option I get this error on application (with or without x509 login): "Client Certification missing for MTLS HoK Token Binding". The login with x509 certificate must be optional to the user. Keycloak is behind nginx reverse proxy.